# php, parse in a ordered HTML list and edit the text in the <li>st without affecting the surrounding HTML tags

Tags: php, html, list, parsing

I'm trying to parse in a HTML list, using PHP, and then read in the content of the lists (e.g. children and young people, residents, professionals) and the tags, append a '/' to the end of each bit of text within the list (except the last item) and then output that, without editing any of the surrounding HTML tags.

Currently I have got it reading in the list and appending the '/' but I'm removing the surrounding tags in the process, does anyone have any suggestions to methods to do this or any functions I should use? Thanks

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li class="inline odd first" itemscope="" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"><a href="https://my.northtyneside.gov.uk/category/75/residents" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="title">Residents</span></a></li> 
        <li class="inline even" itemscope="" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"><a href="https://my.northtyneside.gov.uk/category/175/children-and-young-people" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="title">Children and young people</span></a></li> 
        <li class="inline odd last" itemscope="" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"><span itemprop="title">Professionals</span></li>
    </ol>

    <?php

    function injectSlashes($breadcrumb){

        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->loadHTML($breadcrumb);
        $liList = $doc->getElementsByTagName('li');
        $liValues = array();
        foreach ($liList as $li) {
            $liValues[] = $li->nodeValue;
        }

        $correctBreadcrumb = implode("<span aria-hidden=\"true\">/</span>",$liValues);

        return $correctBreadcrumb;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Do you want all of the tags inside the `<li>` items?

Comment: I want all of the tags to be returned yeah (basically all html in and only add a '/' to the end of the text items except last one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be to change the data you store from each item.

At the moment, you use

```
$liValues[] = $li->nodeValue;
```

which as you've found is just the text of the item.

To store the HTML, you need to use `saveHTML()`.  Normally this may be a document fragment, but you can simplify this to be the first child element in the `<li>` tag...

```
$liValues[] = $doc->saveHTML($li->firstChild);
```

If you need to retain the `<ol>` tag, it's more complicated.  This code extracts the tag and just outputs that content, which will be something like

```
<ol class="breadcrumb"></ol>
```

It then creates the breadcrumb as before and inserts it by replacing the `><` with the `>` breadcrumbs `<`...

```
function injectSlashes($breadcrumb){
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($breadcrumb);
    // Extract the ol
    $ol = $doc->getElementsByTagName('ol')[0];
    // Output the HTML for just the ol tag
    $olText = $doc->saveHTML($ol->cloneNode());
    $liList = $doc->getElementsByTagName('li');
    $liValues = array();
    foreach ($liList as $li) {
        $liValues[] = $doc->saveHTML($li->firstChild);
    }

    $list = implode("<span aria-hidden=\"true\">/</span>",$liValues);
    // Insert the breadcrumbs in the empty ol tag from above
    $correctBreadcrumb = str_replace("><", ">".$list."<", $olText);
    return $correctBreadcrumb;
}
```

Comment: this worked for the <li> tags thank you, but I realise I poorly worded the question, I want to return the whole list including the <ol> tags when returning the function

Comment: Yes Nigel thank you, I've been stuck on that all day thanks!